# PowerShell get shadowstorage maxspace for C drive as string

Tags: string, powershell, max-size

How would I go about getting the maxspace used by shadowstorage on C drive as a string in GB?
Only thing I found so far is this cmdlet which lists all parameters:

```
get-wmiobject win32_shadowstorage
```

But I only need the valued of MaxSpace converted in GB and only for C drive.
The purpose of this is for using in a wpf app later on as if/else statement.
PowerShell seems to be the fastest way to achieve this and the "elderly" vssadmin seems only to accept parameters, not to retrieve anything...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_ShadowStorage"`. You can be interested in the following  [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394433):

- `AllocatedSpace` (*Data type*: `uint64`) Allocated space on the differential area volume.
- `DiffVolume`     (*Data type*: `Win32_Volume`) Reference to the differential volume.
- `Volume`         (*Data type*: `Win32_Volume`) Reference to the original volume.

Properties `DiffVolume` and `Volume` look like (*GUID* can vary)

```
Win32_Volume.DeviceID="\\\\?\\Volume{95570d86-0703-4b5c-8909-c967baecabd3}\\"
```

and this appearance invites you to check the [`Win32_Volume` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515), and **Bingo**! There is the `DriveLetter` property! Putting this together:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_ShadowStorage" | 
ForEach-Object { 
    $aux = $_.Maxspace/1GB
    Get-WmiObject -Class "Win32_Volume" -Filter (
            $_.DiffVolume -replace 'Win32_Volume\.', '') | 
        Select-Object -Property DriveLetter, DeviceID | 
            Where-Object DriveLetter -eq 'C:' | 
                ForEach-Object { [string]$aux }
}
```